# What is the logic behind this string reversal?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

The following program is reversing a string but I am not getting how.

```
s='Marrey has a little lamb'
def reverse(s):
    str=''
    for i in s:
        str=i+str

    return str
print(reverse(s))
```

However when I am writing str=str+i, it is not reversing. What may be the logic behind it? I am a beginner in python, please help.

Comment: To understand what happens, write the iterations down on paper.

Comment: Why don't you just debug and step through each iteration of the loop, and observe the value of str?

Comment: I have observed the values but not getting the logic. The for loop should assign one character at a time in i and then it will be appended to the 'str'. But how is it appending in reverse order?

Comment: @Pratik it is not appending, it is adding it to the **begining** of the string.

Comment: Ok, but why or how in reverse order when i is getting the values in proper order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use a python keyword as a variable (str)
You can test it by adding a print after each iteration:

```
 s='String'
def reverse(s):
    newstring=''
    for i in s:
        newstring=i+newstring
        print(newstring)

    return newstring
print(reverse(s))
```

**output:**

```
S
tS
rtS
irtS
nirtS
gnirtS
gnirtS
```

What `i+newstring` is doing is taking each element and prefixing it to its previous element while iterating through the entire string.

When you use `newstring+i` , it will add the element after the previous element which is the same so it won't work.

Hope this helps.